# Find match of string in Regex, put into variable, tricky string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm very new in this Regex, there's still a lot I don't understand.

1. I see a lot of @, but I can't find it in MSDN. What's the @ for? eg:
   Regex regex = new Regex("@{lalala},", RegexOptions.Compiled);
2. This is what I'm having trouble with. I have this string.

   {BaseClass.InheritClass,Tuple.Create("MachineState",string.Empty)},

What I want to do is get the name of the InheritClass and MachineState, put it into variables.

I tried this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{BaseClass.(?<inheritClassStr>\d+),Tuple.Create\(""(?<machineStateStr>\d+)"",string.Empty\)\},", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I was hoping later in the code I could do something like this:

```
string inheritClassString = inheritClassStr;
string machineStateString = machineStateStr;
```

But it doesn't work, and I do not know how to debug this. I don't know what the Regex captures, so it's very hard for me to debug.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is (as in regular expression):

```
\{BaseClass.(?<inheritClassStr>.*?),Tuple.Create\("(?<machineStateStr>.*?)",string.Empty\)\}
```

to clarify:

`\d` that you used will math only numbers but identifiers in C# tend to contain letters as well.

`.*` would math any character in greedy manner (so the more the better) so it is not a good choice here

`.*?` will math any character but in not greedy manner (so as small set as possible)

And there is no magic in C# so your declarations in regex wont get converted to variables but you need to access those like this:

```
var inheritClassString = regex.Groups["inheritClassStr"].Value;
```

And the `@` on the beginning of string just indicates that c# compiler wont try to interpret special characters that can be put in otherwise not prefixed string such as `\t\n\r` tab, new line, carriage return.

Comment: I still getting unrecognized escape sequence...

I changed my Regex to:

    Regex regex = new Regex("\{BaseClass.(?<inheritClassStr>.*?),Tuple.Create\(\"(?<machineStateStr>.*?)\",string.Empty\)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Still failing. I have 4 unrecognized escape sequence :(

If I never put escape sequence before the quotation mark, the RegEx will fail at the quotation mark...

Comment: That is exactly the error that `@` is for. Prefix your regex with `@` replace `\"` with `""` and your good to go.